# How to use TLP to prevent overheating and conserve battery?

Tags: battery, tlp

I recently installed TLP on my machine since it is recommended to stop overheating and conserve battery power, but I would like to know how to actually use it, configure it, start it, stop it, etc.

Comment: Have you found [this](https://linrunner.de/tlp/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Introduction

TLP is a feature-rich command line utility for Linux, saving laptop battery power without the need to delve deeper into technical details.

Configuration: TLP's default settings are already optimized for battery life, so you may just install and forget it. Nevertheless TLP is highly customizable to fulfill your specific requirements.

#### Start

After installation TLP will start automatically on boot. To avoid having to restart the system the first time, you can start it manually by using this command:

```
sudo tlp start
```

*Note:* Also use this command to apply changes after editing the configuration.

#### Stop

```
sudo tlp stop
```

#### Status

Use the following command to check that TLP is enabled and active:

```
tlp-stat -s
```

Check the output for system status:

```
+++ System Status
State = enabled
Last Run = <Time of system start or last change of power source>
```

*Important:* TLP does not include a daemon and there is no tlp process showing up in the output of `ps`.

#### Version

The command

```
tlp-stat -s
```

states the program version installed in the first output line:

```
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------
```

#### Commands

The following sections describe TLP's set of shell commands:

- `tlp` – Apply TLP’s settings and change mode of operation.
- `tlp-rdw` – Enable, disable or check automatic event based actions on radio devices.
- `tlp-stat` – View TLP’s configuration, system information, kernel power saving settings and battery data.
- [bluetooth, wifi, wwan](https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/radio.html) – Enable, disable, toggle or check the state of built-in bluetooth, wifi and wwan (3G/UMTS, 4G/LTE or 5G) radios:

  ```
  bluetooth [ on | off | toggle ]
  wifi [ on | off | toggle ]
  wwan [ on | off | toggle ]
  ```
- `run-on-ac, run-on-bat` – Conditional execution of a command depending on the current power source:

  ```
  run-on-ac command parameter ...  
  run-on-bat command parameter ...
  ```

Note:

- All commands shown with a preceding `sudo` may also be executed without `sudo` in a root shell
- For even more details refer to the command's manpage: `man <command>`

<sub>**Source:**  revised from [Usage – TLP 1.4 documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/usage/index.html)</sub>